# Convert USB drive from MBR to GPT

Tags: terminal, usb, partition

I have 16 GB SanDisk USB-C drive and want to convert it to GPT on MB Pro 2017. I haven't found any default tools to do this on High Sierra so I downloaded gdisk. So here is what I type in the terminal:

```
sudo gdisk /dev/disk2s1/Volumes/BOOTABLE
```

and the output is:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3
Problem opening /dev/disk2s1/Volumes/BOOTABLE for reading! Error is 20.
```

How can I convert it to GPT?

**EDIT:** 
I converted drive to GPT using `sudo gdisk /dev/disk2` but the following issue appeared:

> Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out! Warning!
>   Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
>   instead of main partition table!
>
> Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
>
> Partition table scan:   MBR: protective   BSD: not present   APM: not
>   present   GPT: damaged

I verified it and got the message:

> Problem: The CRC for the main partition table is invalid. This table
>   may be
>       corrupt. Consider loading the backup partition table ('c' on the recovery &
>       transformation menu). This report may be a false alarm if you've already
>       corrected other problems.
>        Identified 1 problems!

So I tried to do as advised and got this:

> Recovery/transformation command (? for help): c 
>   Warning! This will probably do weird things if you've converted an MBR to GPT form and
>   haven't yet saved the GPT! Proceed? (Y/N):

Should I load backup partition table from disk (rebuilding main) or load MBR and build fresh GPT from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I entered `Recovery/transformation commands` and selected `load MBR and build fresh GPT from it`. After that I chose `write table to disk and exit`. 
Operation completed successfully.